# Remove polygons having less than 4 coordinates in R

Tags: coordinate-system, r, polygon, sp

I have a multiPolygon shapefile of buildings in a particular city. I read it in with `readOGR` and and transform it to my desired planar projection with the following code:

```
buildings_data<-readOGR("buildings.shp")
buildings<- spTransform(buildings_data, CRS("+proj=utm +zone=45 +a=6377299.151
                                        +b=6356098.145120132 
                                        +towgs84=295,736,257,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs "))
```

It gives me the following output along with transforming:

```
There were 19 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
```

All the warnings are:

```
In Polygon(coords = crds) : less than 4 coordinates in polygon
```

So how do I remove these polygons with less than 4 coordinates?

Comment: Are you sure your data has clean geometries?
This might be a repeated question
Check this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/261543/what-does-this-error-means-less-than-4-coordinates-in-polygon

Comment: While three points define a plane, four vertices define a polygon (the first must be repeated to close the shape). Therefore, geometries with fewer than four vertices *can't* be a polygon and are topologically corrupt.

Comment: @RubenFV what do you mean by clean geometries? Can you please explain a bit more? I am new to GIS.

Comment: @Vince yes I got to know that from other answer but can you tell me how do I remove those corrupt geometries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct. 
But you shapefile (buildings) seems to be corrupted and have some **topology errors** and **geometry validity** issues, just as [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/261543/what-does-this-error-means-less-than-4-coordinates-in-polygon.).

You need to inspect and correct your original building data. It is difficult to tell you where the problem lies without having access to it.

An option in **R** to further explore this is the **[cleangeo](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cleangeo/cleangeo.pdf)** package.

```
install.packages("cleangeo")
library(cleangeo)

buildings_data <- readOGR("buildings.shp")
buildings<- spTransform(buildings_data, CRS("+proj=utm +zone=45 +a=6377299.151 +b=6356098.145120132 +towgs84=295,736,257,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs"))
clgeo_IsValid(buildings) # This tells you if the geometry is valid
clgeo_Clean(buildings, errors.only = NULL, strategy = "POLYGONATION",verbose = FALSE)
clgeo_IsValid(buildings) # check again...
```

Or you can also explore and clean the original dataset with QGIS, ArcGIS or similar and check topology and geometry issues.